# How to create a bootable DVD to install Ubuntu 18.04 in Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, windows-10

Yesterday I downloaded Ubuntu ISO file from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Then I used Windows file explorer to burn the ISO to my DVD-R. Then I went to boot manager and selected the DVD drive. It showed "Please select a proper boot device".

I guess I have to install grub bootloader in order to install Linux but I don’t have any idea how to install it on my DVD.

Comment: the contents of the iso

Comment: @Rinzwind if you dont support windows how will i use ubuntu??:(

Comment: How to create a bootable dvd on Windows can be asked on http://superuser.com/ for instance. Though they probably expect more from you than just asking that ;) We here use Ubuntu and are not expected to be users of Windows. Windows only answers get removed here ;-)

Comment: Are you also picking the DVD from your BIOS boot options in case of UEFI?

Comment: yes..i selected it from my bios boot options

Comment: “I guess I have to install grub bootloader in order to install Linux” The ISO should contain the bootloader. Something else must have gone wrong…

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you just burned the iso to DVD, so that the *.iso file is now on DVD. You have to create a running DVD from *.iso file.

So just right mouse click on *.iso file and choose "Burn disc image".

Comment: yes i have done it ..the cd shows all files and folders properly.

Comment: Ok, than it should work if boot option of you DVD has higher prio than your harddisc.

Can you try it with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, just to be sure that it is not caused by newest Ubuntu release (What I have read is, that the installer has some issues).